# Load data before page is loaded AngularJS and NodeJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, node.js, html

i'm a little newie in AngularJS and NodeJS, i have an app that i want to load some data from a mysql db and load that data through Node server and Angular framework, my question is, how can i load the data to show it in a page before its loaded? i'm tryng it but always i get undefined from json var.

This is my code:

```
var app = angular.module('pedidos',[]);
app.service('adminPedidos',function($http){
    this.getAll = function(){
        var data =[];
        var req = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/all',
        };
        return $http(req).then(function(response, status, headers, config) {
            return response;
        }).error(function(response, status, headers, config) {
            alert(response+" "+status);
        });
    };
});
```

and the controller have the following sentence:

```
app.controller('Main'['$scope','$http','adminPedidos',function($scope,$http,$adminPedidos){
    this.json = [];
    this.json = $adminPedidos.json;
    console.log(this.json);
}]);
```

Also in html i have this:

```
<section class="container" ng-controller="Main as controller">
    <section ng-repeat="items in controller.json" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div data-id="{{items.id}}">
            <span class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" name="name">{{items.name}}</span>
            <span class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" name="link"><a href="{{item.link}}">{{items.link}}</a></span>
            <span class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" name="price">{{items.price}}</span>
            <span class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" name="quantity">{{items.quantity}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"><button id="edit" class="btn btn-warning">Editar</button></div>
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"><button id="delete" class="btn btn-danger">Borrar</button></div>
    </section>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service

```
angular.module('pedidos').factory('adminPedidos', ['$http', function ($http) {
  return {
      getAll: function () {
        return $http.get('all'); // or change all to http://localhost:3000/all
      }
   };
}]);
```

Controller

```
angular.module('pedidos').controller('Main'['$scope', 'adminPedidos', function ($scope, adminPedidos) {
        adminPedidos.getAll().success(function (data) {
           $scope.items = data;
        });
}]);
```

html

```
<section class="container" ng-controller="Main">
<section ng-repeat="item in items" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div data-id="{{item.id}}">
        <span class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" name="name">{{item.name}}</span>
        <span class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" name="link"><a href="{{item.link}}">{{item.link}}</a></span>
        <span class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" name="price">{{item.price}}</span>
        <span class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" name="quantity">{{item.quantity}}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"><button id="edit" class="btn btn-warning">Editar</button></div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"><button id="delete" class="btn btn-danger">Borrar</button></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly this is not something that you can completely achieve in a straight forward manner with angular. If you are loading a lot of data then you will have to hide you view and show only when the data has loaded. However if you are loading only a little data, the you could give the following code a try:

```
$scope.$on("$ionicView.beforeEnter", function(){
  //Load data here
  //And bind to scope
})
```

But generally for a solid fix, I always would recommend that you hide the view using ng-show or ng-hide and only show the view once all the data has loaded.

Comment: But the big problem is that i want to bind the var json resources to the view, so i can load the data independently to view, i mean this should work in case of load is binded to json var, don't know if you know what i mean

Comment: Ah you can solve this using two techniques. 1. The long way and probably the best is to parse the json and add individual keys to the data object that is binded to the view. 2. This method is not recommend in the angular doc but you can simply replace your data object which is binded to view with your json object and then call $scope.$apply() which should update the view.

Answer (score 0):

A good way would be to use Location Provider ($locationProvider) or State provider ($stateProvider), where you have the ability to load a view after resolving a promise.

Or else if you are not using any of these, as in your case, since the service is returning promise, have the view updated when it resolves using 'then'

```
    app.controller(){
    this.json = [];
    var self = this;
    adminPedidos.then(function(data){
        self.json = data; //a digest cycle would be required (Depends)
//also, probably use ng-show to show the view (as other person have suggested)
    }, function(err){

    });
    console.log(this.json);
}]);
```